# What should I do with candied citron?

Tags: fruit, italian-cuisine, candy, citrus

My inlaws just gave me a gift of candied whole citron (not just the peel) that they picked up from southern Italy.  It was very thoughtful and just in time for Sukkot!

However, I'm just not sure what to do with it.  I did taste a small slice of it plain and it was pretty good--not at all bitter nor too sweet.

I'd read that you can put it in your cereal, and that it's also used in ricotta pie or panettone--though I don't see myself making those.  Are there other good uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if it comes directly from Southern Italy you could use it to make some Southern Italy specialty like [pastiera napoletana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastiera), [sfogliatelle napoletane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sfogliatelle) or [cannoli siciliani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannoli), all of which require candied fruits.

Traditionally pastiera is done with a mix of candied citron and orange peel plus candied pumpkin (*cucuzzata*) which however is not the easiest ingredient to find.

Citrus is definitely a must for sfogliatelle. There are two types of sfogliatelle *ricce* and *frolle*. Sfogliatelel ricce are better tasting in my opinion, but can be challenging to do at home.

[image]
*Sfogliatella riccia*

[image: Sfogliatella frolla]
*Sfogliatella frolla*

Cannoli traditionally only have candied orange peels, but I guess citron would do well in them anyway.

[image: Cannolo]
*Cannolo siciliano*

Note: the pastry in the Wikipedia photo for pastiera seems way too thick and crumbly. The pastry should be very thin, there just to keep everything together, and should not be the dominant taste.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia reports (without references):

> Succade is sometimes used in cakes, as a filling for pound cake,
>   oliebol, plum pudding, florentines, sfogliatelle, fruitcake or
>   ontbijtkoek. It is also added to raisin bread. Succade is often
>   combined with currants, raisins and cherries. Candied citron peel is
>   often coated in chocolate and eaten as confectionery. Chopped succade
>   is also used in cannoli.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try making panforte with it? i made that a few times with other candied fruits, but can immagine that the freshness of citron would really fit nicely with it